# Hardware monitoring and reporting

Tags: gratis, monitoring, reporting, hardware

I just built a new computer and I'm interested in tracking its health. I want to find a program that will monitor the health of my computer components and generate reports for me to review at any time. Various states I'm interested in are:

- CPU Temp
- GPU Temp
- Fan speeds
- HDD/SSD health
- power usage
- CPU Usage
- Whatever else you can think of

Comment: Which OS?  Windows,Linux,MAC ?

Comment: @cybernard Windows

Comment: System Chronicle is working on something similar at its early stage. Might worth checking it out at: http://www.syschr.com

Answer (score 2):

[CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com/) have an utility named PC Wizard that gives a lot of information about your computer, inlcuding the one you ask, but i don't know if they have logging and/or reporting capabilities, anyway, it may be worth the shot.